# Only use Raspberry Pi HDMI port by my program

Tags: java, linux, raspberry-pi

I am using Arch Linux Arm on my pi, I want my java program (running on pi) to give video output to HDMI port even though the OS is not using the port to output display (I only want my program to access Dispaly, if my program crashes I don't want my linux terminal to be displayed in the monitor), is is possible to do this ??

Comment: Maybe investigate for something called kiosk mode. Don't know if it exists for arch, though.

Comment: Wait a minute, i dont understand your redaction.. You need your display to be used only to show your program and nothing else?, and never show, for example, a linux terminal?

Comment: I did that some weeks ago and there are several small steps inside Raspbian and RPi to achieve that. A solely silent startup, showing only your program at the startup an at the end...

Comment: yes please, can you tell me how ?